# Showing half of the image in the viewfinder for Android Application

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am trying to make an application that, while the camera on the phone is running, only shows half of what the view finder sees. I have tried reading the documentation on accessing the camera hardware, however I am new to development and can't make much of it. Would this even be possible? And if so can someone please offer any tips on how I could go about this? Thanks very much.

Comment: Why not place a view over the `SurfaceView` to cover up the portion you would like the user to not be able to see?

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm not fully understanding what the camera preview is doing and how that whole process works. I think I'll try to understand that better and try this approach. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is a good place to start: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by this? As @B2B explained, it's easy to hide half the preview under some non-transparent view. But this only changes what the uses sees in viewfinder, not what is recorded, for example.

Comment: This should be exactly what I want to accomplish once I figure it out.  I just want to have half of what is seen in the viewfinder hidden. I'm going through the camera documentation now, trying to get the sample camera preview class working